# Bitlocker drive decryption with TPM + password?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

I have a strange situation and I may be out of luck, but I thought I would ask.

I have a drive protected by BitLocker + PIN.

Recently, one of the components on the computer (the graphics card) died, which had me attempt to move the encrypted boot drive to a new PC that had onboard graphics while I awaited a new graphics card to arrive so I could continue working.

The issue is, as you can imagine, the system asked for the recovery key (which I do not have, it was on a USB drive which got overwritten by accident).

Anyways, I didn't think much of it at the time. Figured I would just wait until my new graphics card arrived and installed it back in the original PC and all would be well.

Well, the issue is, when I plugged it back into the original PC I am greeted with the message "secure boot policy has unexpectedly changed- please enter your recovery key"

Now, my question is, am I screwed here? I have both the original TPM and the PIN, so it seems like it would just be a setting or something which is requesting the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some triggers of [BitLocker Recovery Mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-recovery-guide-plan#what-causes-bitlocker-recovery). It might inform you about additional triggers.

To answer your implied question: Can I still get access to your data without the BitLocker Recovery Password or Key when have triggered BitLocker Recovery Mode?

Not likely, sorry.

If you are in for an expirement:

Can the system boot with the broken graphics card?

**Remote Desktop or Blind interaction:**

I know you won't see anything, but if the sytem boots if you put everything back the way it was including boot order, graphics card and other trigger-items, you might have a chance to log-in blindly into Windows and export a recovery password via command line to a usb drive.

- You can try out the steps on a machine with working interface.
- Windows hasn't made the log-sound for years, but if you have a messenger app auto-run you could detect it by seeing yourself coming online via another system.
- You could use remote destop if you have that configured.

To be frank: I don't expect it to work, but if you have nothing else to lose, here you go.